# How to add button to pageblocktable column AND how can i link to Quote pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have a vf called QuotePDF.when i click the button i will open the Quote PDF.

I want to place this button in my pageblock table as one of the column .how can i do that one.

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!quo}" var="q">
        <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Number_New__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!q.From1__c}"/>
         <apex:column>

         </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Is it custom page?

Comment: yes, Is is standard functionality or vf created by you?

Comment: Then I think my answer should fit your requirements :)

Comment: related list in table? isn't that solved?
Or just normal related list?

Comment: no,it is the only thing balance for my project

Comment: Ok, can you edit those question or create new where you specified what you still need? I will try find some time in my work to help you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can craete such button realy easy :)

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:commandButton value="Create PDF" action="/apex/CreatePDF?id={!q.id}"/>
</apex:column>
```

This simple button can redirect you to your landing page. Those defined in action field.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create a apex:column in pageBlocktable and can create a button in that :

```
<apex:column >
  <apex:commandButton value="Test"/>
</apex:column>
```